# PyTorch Experience Replay with multiple inputs

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am running a modified version of the pyTorch deep Q tutorial which I have modified to pass in my own data rather than gym, and one additional input (two inputs in total)

Currently I am generating an individual state for each 'column' of inputs (not sure if this is the correct way though), when trying to pass the second input into my experience replay function it is returning:

```
__new__() takes 5 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Code for `expReplay()`:

---

```
class ReplayMemory(object):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = []
        self.position = 0

    def push(self, *args):
        """Saves a transition."""
        if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
            self.memory.append(None)
        self.memory[self.position] = Transition(*args)
        self.position = (self.position + 1) % self.capacity

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)
```

And my Triggering of the function:

```
memory.push(state,rsistate, action, next_state, next_rsi_state, reward)
```

If anyone has any examples of experience replay using multiple inputs please fire away! <3

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, this was solved by modifying the Transition named tuple to include the additional inputs. Any information on multi input expreplay is still welcome.